# Asymptotic dimension of graph manifold groups

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

> Does every non-geometric graph manifold have fundamental group of asymptotic dimension 3?

This is affirmed in http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1098 for closed graph manifolds, but I am interested in non-closed graph manifolds as well.
Notice that the asymptotic dimension of such groups is always at least 2 (obvious) and at most 3 (by a result of Bell and Dranishnikov).

Answer (score 5):

I should have seen much earlier that it's 2. In fact, every non-closed graph manifold has a finite sheeted cover that fibers over the circle, see [here](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=37203). The fundamental group of such cover is an HNN extension of a free group, so that it has asymptotic dimension at most 2 by the main result of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111087).